# Does Quickbooks need to be installed on the same machine as the SDK

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to use QB SDK on a different machine than QB enterprise is installed on. I have access to the company file on the remote machine via a network path.

Would QB need to be installed on the local machine for that to work or installing the SDK is fine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to have QuickBooks installed on the same machine your app is running on.

Comment: If I install QB on the current machine (app server) then can that QB access the company file being used on the remote machine WHILE still having the QB on the remote machine accessible via QB installation on the remote machine?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your question, but it's very easy to do what you're trying to do. Install QuickBooks on the main computer (computer A). Install QuickBooks on the other computer (computer B). Put the company file on a shared drive hosted on computer A. Computer A opens the company file directly (e.g. C:\path\to\shared\folder\My Company.QBW). Computer B opens the company file on the network share (\\COMPUTER-A\shared\folder\My Company.QBW).

Answer (score 2):

No Quick books does not have to be installed on the same machine that the app is running on.
You will need to have the QBSDK assembly as part of your app or installed on the client machine (assuming c#). Install the Remote data server on the same machine that quick books is on and install remote data client on the client machine. RDS and Client installs are part of the QBSDK Download.

After they have been configured correctly you will be able to query and update your quick books database from the client application. I have been using this for quite a while. Note: I am not using XML directly, but rather the QBSDK / RDS  to handle the connection between the machines.

Google qbxml if this is not what you are looking for.